# strange setopt behavior

Tags: zsh

For certain options, setopt doesn't have an effect.

```
➜  ~  setopt | grep history
extendedhistory
➜  ~  setopt appendhistory
➜  ~  setopt | grep history # appendhistory apparently didn't get set
extendedhistory
➜  ~  setopt sharehistory
➜  ~  setopt | grep history # but sharehistory does
extendedhistory
sharehistory
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setopt` outputs the deviation from the current emulation mode. `appendhistory` is set by default in `zsh` emulation.

To display the status of all options, you can use `set -o`.

Quoting the doc:

> ```
>  If no arguments are supplied, the names of all options currently
>  set are printed.  The form is chosen so as to minimize the
>  differences from the default options for the current emulation (the
>  default emulation being native zsh, shown as <Z> in *note
>  Description of Options::).  Options that are on by default for the
>  emulation are shown with the prefix no only if they are off, while
>  other options are shown without the prefix no and only if they are
>  on.  In addition to options changed from the default state by the
>  user, any options activated automatically by the shell (for
>  example, SHIN_STDIN or INTERACTIVE) will be shown in the list.  The
>  format is further modified by the option KSH_OPTION_PRINT, however
>  the rationale for choosing options with or without the no prefix
>  remains the same in this case.
> ```